# Get Value out of specific Column if first Value match

Tags: python, excel, if-statement, vlookup

I need to get a specific value out of f.e. column 4 of my imported Excel if the Value in column 1 matched with the earlier imported number (lets assume the value is defined as V). So that means if Value Column A = V than get me the value of column 4. All the Values in Column 1 are numbers and the value in column 4 is a mix betweend letters and numbers.

I tried different things but none worked until I realized that even if I search for the value with 0000 in pd the result is False. I imported the Excel with pd.read_excel.

Can you please provide some help - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my question is the following:

```
pd_specificline = pd[pd['Name of column'] == float(Value that needs to be matched)]['Value that should be importat].sum()
```

The float is needed because diffrent structures are used.